# Different Imphash for same PE file

Tags: python, malware, sysinternals

I am analyzing a windows executable **(C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe)**. The Imphash value calculated with Python is different from the one shown with PE studio. How can Imphash for a same file be different when computed using two different tools?

What's missing here ?

**Imphash Python:** 1effe65a4f251e4ae9fa8551f9fcdabb

**Imphash PeStudio:** 370E0F2A87317776FEB42A7B32DD037B

[image: PE studio Result]

[image: Python Result]

Answer (score 2):

On 64-bit systems, the path `C:\Windows\System32` is virtualized – 64-bit processes can access it directly, but 32-bit processes are magically redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWow64` instead.

Your "pestudio" tool is 32-bit, so it is actually seeing the 32-bit version of xcopy.exe rather than the 64-bit one.

```
Python 3.9.4 [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]

>>> pefile.PE(r"C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe").get_imphash()
'1effe65a4f251e4ae9fa8551f9fcdabb'

>>> pefile.PE(r"C:\Windows\SysWow64\xcopy.exe").get_imphash()
'370e0f2a87317776feb42a7b32dd037b'
```